# php function filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) in console giving error [bus error]

Tags: php, filter-var

I use php function filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) to validate an IP. Its working ok when i run it via a http url.

but when i run it via php console it give me error

```
Bus error
```

the code is as follows,

```
$ip = $argv[1];

if (!filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)===false)

{

}

else

{
echo 'ip address is not valid';
exit;

}   

echo $ip;

exit;
```

Comment: first var_dump $argv

Comment: after do var_dump i get **string(9) "127.0.0.1"**

Comment: I found this: _italic_ a bus error is a fault raised by hardware, notifying an operating system (OS) that a process is trying to access memory that the CPU cannot physically addres _italic_ BTW change the first condition to === true instead of !=== false

Answer (score 0):

I upgrade php version from 5.1.6 to 5.6.3 it worked.

Answer (score 0):

i think this is usefull

```
$ip = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
if(!filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)===false)
{

}
else
{
    echo 'ip address is not valid';
    exit;
}   
echo $ip;
exit;
```